# How to check if byte array is empty or not?

Tags: java, resteasy

I am using following code to get uploaded file.

```
 @POST
    @Path("update")
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public boolean updateWorkBookMaster(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
        try {
            //get form data
            Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();

            //get uploaded file
            List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("workBookFile");
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputParts.get(0).getHeaders();
            InputStream inputStream = inputParts.get(0).getBody(InputStream.class, null);
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

now i want to check whether this `byte[]` is empty or not,
while debugging when i have not uploaded any file it shows its length as `9`, why its `9` not `0`.

Comment: maybe because it still contains header info

Comment: An empty array is simply one with a length of 0.

Comment: @JunedAhsan you are right its header info, for this can i check as if(bytes != null && bytes.length >10) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement null check for files this way:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.ContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;

@POST
@Path("update")
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public boolean updateWorkBookMaster(FormDataMultiPart multiPartData) {
    try {
        final FormDataBodyPart workBookFilePart = multiPartData.getField("workBookFile");
        final ContentDisposition workBookFileDetails = workBookFilePart.getContentDisposition();
        final InputStream workBookFileDocument = workBookFilePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

        if (workBookFileDetails.getFileName() != null || 
            workBookFileDetails.getFileName().trim().length() > 0 ) {
            // file is present
        } else {
            // file is not uploadded
        }
    } ... // other code
}
```